Movie about a man/the devil saving a girl's life
I watched the movie (or it could be series?) around 2004 (I think) on the TV (meaning it could be an older movie), it was in English, so I'm assuming it was an American production. 
The first scene I recall is a with girl walking under a church (could be other building) on a square and a statue fell off that building onto her, but in the last second a guy came from nowhere and saved her. 
Then during the whole movie he wanted to have sexual intercourse with her everywhere, including in a church. I assumed he was the devil because of that and other weird things happening, which I don't really remember. Then she was so fed up, she went back to the square under that statue, exactly where she stood at the begging and screamed "I want my life back", or so. 
The statue then fell on her and the guy/devil saved another girl. 

It remember me End of Days   https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/End_of_Days_(film)

Unfortunately it's not it, but thanks!
